# How to extract class from Java generic class to satisfy compiler?

Tags: java, generics

I am fully aware this question was asked many times, but I cannot find an answer to it. :/

I have one parametrized class:

```java
public class MessageType<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public MessageType(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<T> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

And several static objects of this class:

```java
static final MessageType<String> TYPE_A = new MessageType<>(String.class);
static final MessageType<Double> TYPE_B = new MessageType<>(Double.class);
static final MessageType<List<String>> PROBLEM_TYPE = new MessageType(List.class);
```

The problem is that I have to omit diamond operator and stick to unchecked cast of `MessageType` to `MessageType<List<String>>` in the last line.

I would like to write something like

```java
static final MessageType<List<String>> PROBLEM_TYPE = new MessageType<>(List<String>.class);
```

but `List<String>.class` cannot be computed in runtime as, you know, type erasure. :D

➥ Is there any way to comply with the compiler, and avoid unchecked casts? (It has already costed me an hour due to my negligence and lack of attention)

Comment: Extend it with a `CollectionMessageType<T, C extends Collection<T>> extends MessageType<C>` and pass both collection and item class in the constructor?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to use the Class<T> for? It might help to provide a tailored workaround.

Comment: @daniu, It may be a good idea, but I am not sure if inheritance is the right solution. I feel it'd make everything overcomplicated here.

Comment: @k5_, we have another class that contains this MessageType<T>, payload of the said T type, and some technical data, such as the time of the message was created, who created it, etc. That may be the topic for another question. :D

Comment: One workaround:  `static final MessageType<String[]> STRINGS_TYPE = new MessageType(String[].class);`.  It’s not a big burden on other code to convert between an array and a List.

Comment: @Xobotun You can avoid unnecessary casts! You can fully specify the parameterized type of your messages by casting (only once) what you pass into the constructor. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the unchecked cast here; `List<String>` is not a `Class<?>` but a `ParameterizedType` (both extend/implement `Type` but have no further common parent). You can store and use the type information of `List<String>` (with an `ParameterizedType`). But there will always be some unchecked cast to get back to `List<String>`.

There are some options for workarounds. Most are tailored to the actual usecase.

You can move the unchecked cast into MessageType:

```
public <T> static MessageType<List<T>> createListMessage(Class<T> innerType){
    return (MessageType<List<T>>) (Object) new MessageType(List.class);
}
```

If you need Class to create a new Instance. Provide a `Supplier<T>`.

```
   private final Supplier<T> supplier;
   public MessageType(Supplier<T> supplier){
       this.supplier = supplier;
   }
   public T newType(){
      return supplier.get();
   }

   MessageType<String> STRINGS = new MessageType(String::new);
   MessageType<List<String>> STRING_LIST = new MessageType(ArrayList::new);
```

If you need it for serialization a Supertype-Token is an option.

Comment: It's a pity I can't avoid unnecessary casts here. However, I liked this idea of creating a factory method for the sole purpose of creating List<T>: it may seem ugly, but it has short and clear implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid unnecessary casts!
See below:

```
public static class MessageType<T> {
    static MessageType<List<String>> STRINGS_LIST_TYPE1 = new MessageType<>(List.class);
    static MessageType<List<String>> STRINGS_LIST_TYPE2 = new MessageType<>();
    static MessageType<Double> DOUBLE_TYPE = new MessageType<>(Double.class);
    static MessageType<String> STRING_TYPE = new MessageType<>(String.class);

    List<T> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    Class<T> clazz;

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
    MessageType(Class<? extends T> clazz) { this.clazz = (Class) clazz; }

    MessageType() { this.clazz = null; }

    void addMessage(T message) { messages.add(message); }
    T getMessage(int i) { return messages.get(i); }
    Class<T> getClazz() { return this.clazz; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // MessageType<List<String>> STRINGS_LIST_TYPE1 = new MessageType<>(List.class);
        STRINGS_LIST_TYPE1.addMessage(new ArrayList<String>()); // no compile issues
        STRINGS_LIST_TYPE1.addMessage(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // compile error "not applicable  for the arguments (ArrayList<Integer>)"
        List<String> message1 = STRINGS_LIST_TYPE1.getMessage(0); // no warnings!
        Class<List<String>> clazz1 = STRINGS_LIST_TYPE1.getClazz(); // no warnings!

        // MessageType<List<String>> STRINGS_LIST_TYPE2 = new MessageType<>()
        STRINGS_LIST_TYPE2.addMessage(new ArrayList<String>()); // no compile issues
        STRINGS_LIST_TYPE2.addMessage(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // compile error "not applicable  for the arguments (ArrayList<Integer>)"
        List<String> message2 = STRINGS_LIST_TYPE2.getMessage(0); // no warnings!
        Class<List<String>> clazz2 = STRINGS_LIST_TYPE2.getClazz(); // no warnings! but returns null
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, if you dont need `getClazz()` it is viable. It all depends on where/if you need the actual type information.

Comment: Second thought: you dont need the sentinel at all. Just have a no arg constructor and do `MessageType<List<String>> PROBLEM_TYPE = new MessageType<>();`

Comment: Good call on the unnecessary sentinel value, I was focused on the idea of needing to pass a parameter and complicated it more than it needed to be. At least it still shows that OP can avoid unnecessary casts. Also, now I've added in how `getClazz` can be handled.

Comment: You just added the raw/unsafe cast the OP wanted to avoid. You showed what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that OP didn't like the cast at instantiation but a cast is absolutely necessary if OP *actually* needs the Class object, which I expect they don't. However, if they don't like casting at the location of instantiation, they could simply handle it in the constructor instead, as I have shown in my updated example.